# How to make a dripping text effect in blender 3.0?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I was trying to make a fluid simulation following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/PG8PL2AMWnI) but fluid settings were changed in blender 2.8 and I'm at a loss. I don't know how to break the fluid into small drips like in this video. It's just constant streams.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdrwc.jpg) what I want..  It's a three-second-long video:

[image]

My blend file.
[image]

Comment: just increase the resolution. If that doesn't help, pls provide blend file because you didn't show us any settings you have made (and no, not everybody wants to watch an 8 minute video just to prepare an answer to your question).

Comment: @Chris Thanks for answering. I don't think changing the resolution is the solution. It is still a constant stream. Also, I have updated my question. A three-second video of the effect I want, and a .blend file.

Comment: A setting for "Honey" or heavy oil, implies Viscosity.  Yours is enabled, but is set to 0.0.

Comment: Diffusion also has a "Honey" quickset -- yours appears to be the default

Comment: @james_t I did both of these things already. Setting Viscosity higher and using honey preset. The liquid just wouldn't separate like in the video. It just becomes a big chunk of liquid falling very slowly. Maybe I need to increase resolution like a thousand or something?

Comment: You're posting is a good challenge and I can't figure it out, unless I add other effectors/collision with drivers to [simulate](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qitzvivqxq4c7fc/dripping%20text.blend?dl=0).  I'll try to re-post your question as I have enough rep point to create a bounty after a few days, which may attract more expert help.

Comment: perhaps follow [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/286236/dripping-fluid-effect-challenge) post

Answer (score 4):

### 2.79

Quite interesting, this dripping works in 2.79 with just default setup :) In general it is not too much expected behaviour, but works great for your purpose.
So ... one way is to download 2.79 and **Bake** fluid there. Than **Export as Alembic** (.abc) file.

### 3.xx

Speaking to **Blender 3** - behaviour is different, because it uses completely different fluid solver (**Mantaflow**).

The way I accomplished this result ...

- Set Domain's > *Field Weights* > **Gravity zero**
- Add **Force Field** > *Force, Shape > Plane, Strength* -0.6, enable Falloff > **Max Distance** with value that ends bellow Inflow object

[image]

[image]

Or you can try **Particle System > Fluid** and render as Object (Metaballs).

---

**Notes to your blend file:** Try to simplify your Inflow object, there is no a need to bevel edges for simulation and also don't use Dimension of this object 32 m since world scale matters the dimension define tally will affect result. Don't waste your computation power and time – scale domain object as small as possible.

Comment: Interesting, indeed I thought the clumping didn't seem natural without perhaps some other objects underneath as collisions to obstruct/gather particles.

Comment: @james_t ... now I got something useful :) Probably too late, but it didn't let me a sleep. Idea for solution came from appearance in 2.79 where it looks like an inflow levitates and just a drops are leaking. So the trick here is zero gravity and Empty object as Force Field bellow an inflow object with Falloff > Max Distance up to the bottom part of the text, that attracts (catches) lower parts of liquid.

Comment: "zero gravity and Empty object as Force Field bellow an inflow object with Falloff"!  makes sense.